# Parameterized query expects a parameter value which was not supplied. Parameter name: 0

Tags: asp.net, razor, web, webmatrix

I am trying to store image(on at a time) into database using Webmatrix **SQL SERVER CE DATABSE**.
I have a query and almost everything works when i try to insert image into a folder but when i try to insert into database i face 
"Parameterized query expects a parameter value which was not supplied. Parameter name: 0" error.
here is my code

```
@{

    WebImage photo = null;
    var newFileName = "";
    var imagePath = "";

    if(IsPost){
        var image=Request.Form["Image"];
        var category=Request.Form["category"];

        photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
        if(photo != null){
            newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +
                Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
            imagePath = @"img\images\" + newFileName;

            photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
            <h1>Uploaded Successfully1</h1>
        }

        var db=Database.Open("Task5");
        var queryString="INSERT into images(Category,Image) VALUES (@0,@1) ";
        db.Execute(queryString,image,category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the values @0,@1 coming from? Have you added the parameters somewhere i cannot see?

Comment: They are actually 
var image=Request.Form["Image"];
        var category=Request.Form["category"];

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type image is, but one problem in your code is that you swapped @0 and @1 so that you're putting image (@0) into Category and Category (@1) into image.